# Routing API: does calculateisoline ignore the "maxpoints" and "resolution" parameters?

Tags: here-api

The documentation at https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html describes the parameters "maxpoints" and "resolution".

However, the query results does not seem to change regardless of what values are provided for these parameters. Are they deprecated, not yet implemented, or broken?

My intention is to reduce the number of points and/or decrease resolution in order to improve performance for large distances, hundreds of kilometers.

When distance approaches 200km and above, the error "NOROUTE: Calculation failed. Distance was too big" is usually returned. (Even though the documentation says "There is no limitation for distance of isoline, but if you specify more than 500 km, the quality and performance of the isoline will decrease.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These parameters are only in new isoline service 7.2 - the one I mentioned above. The old service does not have them and it was added to documentation by mistake. It will be fixed shortly. Note the use of these parameters will have no effect on performance.

Otherwise, could you please share with us examples of failing requests?

Comment: Thanks for the update!

This request for a 400km distance:
https://route.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculateisoline.json?mode=fastest;pedestrian;traffic:disabled&start=59,5.6&distance=400000&app_id=redacted&app_code=redacted

Returns: NOROUTE: Calculation failed. Distance was too big.

Comment: I just noticed that requesting car routes instead of pedestrian seems to raise the distance threshold before errors are generated. It mostly works fine up to around 800km distances, at which point I sometimes get the previously mentioned error, and sometimes a HTTP 504 gateway timeout at around 60 seconds.
This mostly solves my problem, so I'm marking this as answered. Would appreciate further updates if anything changes though!

Comment: Alright, excellent! Thanks for the feedback. Please regularly check the online documentation http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resources.html as the new Isoline API is to come in the next months.